# Verificar com REGEX VBA se telefone é fixo ou móvel (verificando 3º número no regex)

Tags: regex, vba, excel-vba

Tenho que fazer um REGEX VBA que verifique o número de telefone neste padrão, pensei em tentar identificar o 3º número e verificar se ele é diferente de 9 ou 8, ficando assim:

Celular       51**9**92656588  - retornando TRUE

Celular       51**9**2656588   - retornando TRUE

Telefone Fixo 51**3**3542737   - retornando FALSE

- Obs: Estou tratando a retirada de "()" e "-" com este Regex aqui: `\\[\-()]\g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problema RegEx

O problema da sua Expressão Regular é que ela não valida, por exemplo se um número fixo começar com 4? Muitos telefones comerciais começam com 4, principalmente em São Paulo, que esgotou os seus números que iniciam com 3.

E se o número estiver no padrão antigo? Com 8 dígitos?

### Solução

Você pode utilizar Regex como função do VBA para validar isto.

### Regex

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

#### Expressão

A expressão para encontrar números de celular é a seguinte: `^(?:\d{2})?(?:[6-9]\d{7}|9\d{8})$` em conjunto com algumas verificações no código.

Em que encontra números que começam ou não com dois dígitos e após com 6,7,8 e 9 (números de celular) e possuam 7 dígitos após iniciar com estes números ou que iniciem com 9 e possuam 8 dígitos após.

> Obs.: Em São Paulo os números que iniciam com 5 são híbridos entre telefonia fixa e móvel. ([teleco](http://www.teleco.com.br/num_cel.asp)). Portanto, não há uma regra clara para os números que iniciam com 5 e foram considerados fixos.

O [demo do Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zUH2AX/11) pode ser visto.

Caso deseje apenas verificar se possui o número 9 e depois 8 dígitos, utilize a seguinte expressão: `^(?:\d{2})?9\d{8}$`

### UDF (User Defined Function) no Excel VBA

#### Código

Primeiro insira esta função em um módulo.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ValidarCelular(Myrange As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    'Padrão RegEx
    strPattern = "^(?:\d{2})?(?:[6-9]\d{7}|9\d{8})$"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        'Retirar espaços
        strInput = Replace(Myrange.Value, " ", "")
        'Retirar '-'
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "-", "")
        'Retirar parênteses
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "(", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, ")", "")

        'Verifica o comprimento da string, para verificar um número inválido
        If Len(strInput) > 11 And IsNumeric(strInput) Then
            GoTo ErrHandler
        Else
            'RegEx
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With
                If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                    ValidarCelular = "Celular"
                Else
                    ValidarCelular = "Fixo"
                End If
        End If
    End If
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' Tratamento de Erro
    ValidarCelular = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

#### Resultado

O teste foi feito com dados de validação na coluna A e inserindo a função `=ValidarCelular(A1)` na coluna B.

[image: Resultado]

#### Explicação Código

1. Cria a função `ValidarCelular` com `MyRange` como variável de entrada, ou seja, uma célula de variável de entrada.
2. Adiciona o padrão da Regex em `strPattern`.
3. Verifica se `strInput` não possui espaços, parênteses e hifens.
4. Verifica se possui mais do que 11 caracteres e se é numérico.
5. Valida com a expressão regular se é um número de celular ou fixo.

Comment: Na verdade Daniel, eu já faço o Regex Inicial, que comentaste, preciso apenas da possibilidade de checar o 3º número. Que foi o que o Vitor respondeu abaixo, porém irei testar, desde já agradeço!! <3

Comment: Alteramos a sua função, como descrito Daniel e funcionou! Valeuuu!

Answer (score 1):

Para checar apenas o terceiro dígito, sem se preocupar com a validação do número completo (supondo que já foi feita antes), pode usar o seguinte RegEx:

`/^..(8|9)/g`

O circunflexo detecta o início da string, o ponto serve como coringa e os caracteres de dentro dos parênteses serão checados para determinar a presença de um *ou* ( `|` ) outro.

Comment: Funciona, é exatamente o necessário para verificar o 3º número, valeu!